# Не получаеться скачать картинку C#

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Нашел много всяких вопросов на эти темы но не один мне не помогает.
Возьмем картинку которую я получаю с помощью vk api
https://pp.userapi.com/c625127/v625127790/2a520/DjJKxD7QOYA.jpg
Перепробывал много способов

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("https://pp.userapi.com/c625127/v625127790/2a520/DjJKxD7QOYA.jpg");
client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg");
```

При открытие файла вылетает ошибка: Средству просмотра фотографий Windows не удалось вывести это изображение, так как файл пуст.

Помогите, взаранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте добавить как описано в ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307684/webclient-error-when-downloading-file-from-https-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://pp.userapi.com/c625127/v625127790/2a520/DjJKxD7QOYA.jpg");
    await Task.Run(() => client.DownloadFile(uri, "picture.jpg"));
    Process.Start("picture.jpg");
}
```